# CSS Display affects jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have run into a strange phenomena I believe and I was wonder if anyone has a the answer to why this occurs.  I have been doing a lot of manipulation of images for a photography site using a custom jQuery slideshow I created and have run into some problems.

I have a gallery here: http://www.daemondeveloper.com/photography/gallery.php

I have been adding some functions that resize the images in this gallery so that they scale to the size of the preview image size. As you can see, the very last image is panoramic and does not fill up the entire height of the div even though I have javascript telling it to resize.

If you refresh the page, the javascript seems to work all of a sudden and the pictures scales how it should.

Now try clicking on the panoramic picture of the girl and my slideshow will appear displaying the image scaled and centered vertically using jQuery. The function below is what handles clicking on the small image previews in the gallery.

If you look at where the commented `changeSize()` function is, that is where I USED to have the function and the scaling did not work. Then I moved it after the .show() functions which show my slideshow and now it works. So it appears that the display:none; affected how the javascript fired because when I debugged, the currentImg object was null, as if the .slides selector did not exist when it was set to display:none;. Is this really happening or am I just seeing a side effect of something else?

If this is really happening it may have something to do with the cause of the first problem I stated about the panoramic image not scaling on the first load of the gallery.php page.

```
$('.imgHolder').click(function(){
    currentPosition = $('.imgHolder').index(this);

    $('#slideShow').width(slideWidth);

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slideContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides.css({
    'float' : 'left',
    'width' : slideWidth
  });

    // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
    $('#slideInner').css('width', (slideWidth * numberOfSlides));

    // Hide left arrow control on first load
    manageControls(currentPosition);

    $('#slideInner').css('margin-left' , slideWidth*(-currentPosition));

    //changeSize(); used to be here

    $('#filter').show();
    $('#photoWrap').show();

            //Change image scale and center
    changeSize();
});
```

And here is the changeSize() function that does the scaling and centering

```
 function changeSize(){

  currentSlide = $('.slide').get(currentPosition);
  currentImg = $(currentSlide).children('img:first')[0];
  imgRatio =  $(currentImg).height() / $(currentImg).width(); 

if(imgRatio < slideRatio)
{
    $(currentImg).addClass('landscape');
    //Vertically align
    var thisHeight = $(currentImg).height();
    $(currentImg).css('margin-top', ($('#slideShow').height()/2)-(thisHeight/2));

}else{
    $(currentImg).addClass('portrait');
}


}
```

Comment: first off, I would advise you to modify your function to instead say `currentImg = $(currentSlide).children("img").first();` Using the `img:first` requires much more overhead, and that could actually solve the problem - somethimes these things are caused by a script taking too long. I'll keep looking...

Comment: where did you scale the height on document.ready?

Comment: thanks ill change it and try it out. Yeah, on document.ready I call a function that initializes all these variables and such and then waits for these events to be fired. Its as if the javascript tries to access the images BEFORE the image is actually ready though

Comment: btw i changed my paths a second ago, i just updated the link above with the new path to the web page

Comment: Okay, do you have any scripts that act based on the way that you navigate to the page? The reason I ask is that if you click the gallery nav button it links you to galleries.php (same path as your hyperlink, above) and it works fine - on refresh it messes up also

Comment: also, in the interest of debugging, have you tried to see what happens if you move that last image into a different position in the order of the images?

Comment: The width of any HTML element with `display: none;` is going to be 0. That's why you were having issues until you moved the resizing function after the show function.

Comment: so the images loading inside of my unordered list don't hold their image properties (height, width, etc) until they are actually shown. That is good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#gallery ul li').each(function() {
    var img = $(this).children('div').children('img').first();
    var ratio = img.height() / img.width();
    var goal = img.parent('div').height() / img.parent('div').width();

    if (ratio < goal) {
        img.addClass('portrait');

        img.css('margin-left', -(img.width() / 2) + ($(this).children('div').width() / 2));
    } else {
        img.css('width', '100%');
    }
});
```

Here I removed the unnecessary `$()` instances from your code, as you have already selected the element that you wish to call your methods on when you set the `img` variable. I doubt that this redundancy is the ultimate issue, but it is a good place to start.

Update your code to this and let's debug from there.

EDIT:

I think I found your error (well, I found one at least):

```
function configGallery()
{

var currentPosition;
var slides = $('.slide')
var currentSlide;
var currentImg;
var slideWidth = 720;
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
...
}
```

Do you see what's wrong here? You forgot a semi-colon after `var slides = $('.slide')` and that could be your issue. Honestly, I'm surprised any of your scripts ran at all. Missing semi-colons usually crash the whole thing.

UPDATE:

Here are a few more selectors for you to remove the $() from when you get a chance:

```
function changeSize(){

      currentSlide = $('.slide').get(currentPosition);
      currentImg = $(currentSlide).children('img').first();
      imgRatio =  $(currentImg).height() / $(currentImg).width(); 

    if(imgRatio < slideRatio)
    {
        $(currentImg).addClass('landscape');
        //Vertically align
        var thisHeight = $(currentImg).height();
        $(currentImg).css('margin-top', ($('#slideShow').height()/2)-(thisHeight/2));

    }else{
        $(currentImg).addClass('portrait');
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Okay I wrote you a [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj3RM/2/) to help you re-write your image-sizing function. I'll work on prettying it up and putting it in a plugin for you.

UPDATE:

Here's the same function again in a quick and dirty plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/Wj3RM/3/
I didn't pretty it up though - I figured it would be easier for you to adapt and modify like this.

Comment: WHOA! thanks for that catch. Thats what I thought too...Why would it even run with that error?? Lol, no wonder I didn't catch the error..the browser didn't even show an error in my console. Weird. lemme update my code and ill let you know what happens

Comment: I updated my code and added more images to the gallery to see if it was because that image was last in the list. Still, that one image appears to not be resizing how it should on the first load. As soon as you reload the page, however, it works. I think it is caching the image on the first load, so the second load is able to use that cached width and height for reference. Idk how to make it work on the first load though

Comment: No, I don't think so - unless it's the web-server that's doing the caching, which wouldn't make much sense to me in this situation. Is that the only image that is that long? becasue if you can find another (or duplicate the image) and put that in there, we could see if there is something that the script doesnt like about the image

Comment: ok, i put another panoramic image in the gallery and this one will not resize at all! even when I reload the page. Try it out. I must be doing something wrong with the javascript but I can't figure out what

Comment: it's actually what I expected - neither of the images are actually resizing on load - i cant seem to figure out why they are when you reload or click gallery but let's start from the top and make a little script to adjust the image down to the right size

Comment: I found something interesting. While debugging through the each() event I run on each <li>, all the variables are assigned fine until it gets to the panoramic images. When it hits them, the img object is assigned an HTMLImageElement, EXCEPT the height and width is not set. They both are 0. No idea why it would work for some images but not others...

Comment: start doing some console.logs on everything you can think of lol

Comment: thanks for the plugin. I will try putting it in. Either way, I accepted ur answer because of all the help. Hopefully it works

Comment: Any time. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more help